# Why is it necessary for a thread to sleep? Is it required only for Sync or also for Async data processing?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, sleep

According to the standards, sleep will make the calling thread sleep until some seconds on Linux and some milliseconds on Windows. But why is this required anyway? Will the thread block the access to it like mutex or it just becomes inactive? What are the consequneces of this to happen, though I am not adding any code here, I need theoretical explanation for my doubts. Sorry for being such a newb.

Comment: You mean thread sleeps by calling function sleep() explicitly or when waiting for some resources (such as, `lock.acquire()`, `condition.wait()`)

Comment: Well like we have 3 threads starting in main function, for each thread begin a sleep of 1 sec is called that is 3 threads and 2 sleep function calls in between them. So why a sleep after a thread begins??

Comment: Calling `sleep()` in between starting threads is not required. Chances are, the second thread you start relies on the first having been already started. `t1.start(); t2.start()` does not guarantee that the code inside t1 will execute before t2 is started. Calling `t1.start(); Thread.sleep(1000); t2.start()` does not guarantee it either, but makes it very likely. It is far from advisable, but will probably work in 99.99% of the cases...

Comment: thank you @xpa1492 its becoming a little clear for me. But how can be that possible using sleep the first thread will run?? well my doubt is why a sleep? I guess is that once a thread start it will be blocked by sleep until a client calls the thread again?